# Docker run expand parameter using variable defined using ARG

Tags: docker

This is my simple Dockerfile. The issue is `SCALA_VERSION` variable in the line `wget -q --no-cookies ...` does not get interpolated. I am not sure how to fix that. I appreciate any help or hint.

```
ARG SCALA_MAJOR_VERSION="2.13"
ARG SCALA_MINOR_VERSION="7"
ARG SCALA_VERSION="$SCALA_MAJOR_VERSION.$SCALA_MINOR_VERSION"

FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine AS base
LABEL version="$SCALA_VERSION"

WORKDIR /usr/lib

RUN apk add --no-cache bash \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies wget ca-certificates \
  && wget -q --no-cookies "https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/${SCALA_VERSION}/scala-${SCALA_VERSION}.tgz" -O - | gunzip | tar x \
  && apk del build-dependencies \
  && rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Logs:

```
➜  compiler-toolchain git:(master) ✗ docker build . -t cool
Sending build context to Docker daemon  16.54MB
Step 1/18 : ARG SCALA_MAJOR_VERSION="2.13"
Step 2/18 : ARG SCALA_MINOR_VERSION="7"
Step 3/18 : ARG SCALA_VERSION="$SCALA_MAJOR_VERSION.$SCALA_MINOR_VERSION"
Step 4/18 : FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine AS base
 ---> c89120dcca4c
Step 5/18 : LABEL maintainer="boyland@uwm.edu"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eb84f71065ca
Step 6/18 : LABEL version="$SCALA_VERSION"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 23f11d22b6cb
Step 7/18 : WORKDIR /usr/lib
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8762269e3700
Step 8/18 : RUN apk add --no-cache bash   && apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies wget ca-certificates   && wget -q --no-cookies "https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/${SCALA_VERSION}/scala-${SCALA_VERSION}.tgz" -O - | gunzip | tar x   && apk del build-dependencies   && rm -rf /tmp/*
 ---> Running in 0cc02cf39a42
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20211120-r0)
(2/4) Installing ncurses-libs (6.3_p20211120-r0)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.1.1-r0)
(4/4) Installing bash (5.1.8-r0)
Executing bash-5.1.8-r0.post-install
Executing busybox-1.34.1-r3.trigger
OK: 10 MiB in 24 packages
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing libunistring (0.9.10-r1)
(2/4) Installing libidn2 (2.3.2-r0)
(3/4) Installing wget (1.21.2-r2)
(4/4) Installing build-dependencies (20211220.220536)
Executing busybox-1.34.1-r3.trigger
OK: 13 MiB in 28 packages
gunzip: invalid magic
tar: short read
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache bash   && apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies wget ca-certificates   && wget -q --no-cookies "https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/${SCALA_VERSION}/scala-${SCALA_VERSION}.tgz" -O - | gunzip | tar x   && apk del build-dependencies   && rm -rf /tmp/*' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't? The build log shows the command before variable replacement, so that will show ${SCALA_VERSION}. But the actual command will have 2.13.7, I think.

Comment: @HansKilian I added an update

Comment: The update shows that the three commands *combined* returned an exit code of `1`. `gunzip` had invalid magic; it never even got to the `wget` part.

Comment: If I don't use `SCALA_VERSION` and hardcode `2.13.7` it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine AS base` that does it. The ARGs set before you base on the new image aren't carried over. You need to move the ARG statements to after the FROM like this

```
FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine AS base
ARG SCALA_MAJOR_VERSION="2.13"
ARG SCALA_MINOR_VERSION="7"
ARG SCALA_VERSION="$SCALA_MAJOR_VERSION.$SCALA_MINOR_VERSION"

LABEL version="$SCALA_VERSION"

WORKDIR /usr/lib

RUN apk add --no-cache bash \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies wget ca-certificates \
  && wget -q --no-cookies "https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/${SCALA_VERSION}/scala-${SCALA_VERSION}.tgz" -O - | gunzip | tar x \
  && apk del build-dependencies \
  && rm -rf /tmp/*
```